# apk to dex conversion

Tags: android, apk, dex

How to convert **.apk** files to **.dex** files?

Please help.

Answer (score 18):

- Rename the .apk to .zip
- Extract the files from the zip
- In the extracted files, you will get your desired dex file

Why would you need the dex file though? Its byte code file for dalvik VM.

Answer (score 5):

An APK is actually a ZIP file. So you can decompress it with:

```
unzip app.apk
```

The DEX file is in the decompressed folder.

From your question I think now you are done. Decompiling the DEX file is another story.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find a dissambler: http://code.google.com/p/smali/
And in this two post you can get more information about the process:
http://zeaster.blogspot.com/2007/11/how-to-decompile-dex-file-on-android_28.html
http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2009/01/disassembling-dex-files.html

Comment: Your links are about how to decompile dex files. The question was how to get the dex, not how to decompile the dex to smil

Comment: any one have better idea how to get dex files from apk.

Comment: hi Aitor  i just extracted setting.apk.zip(Setting app) in android3.2 and i didn't got classes.dex ,could any one can help me what is the problem ??